# Including Auth inside blade form component

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have the following code:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    @include('component.input',[
        'label' => 'Last Name',
        'name' => 'last_name',
        'type' => 'text',
        'placeholder' => 'Li',
        'class' => '',
        'errorMessage' => "required"
    ])
</div>
```

I want to do something like:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    @include('component.input',[
        'label' => 'Last Name',
        'name' => 'last_name',
        'type' => 'text',
        'placeholder' => "{{Auth::user()->last_name}}"
        'class' => '',
        'errorMessage' => "required"
    ])
</div>
```

But its returning syntax errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in the context of PHP when inside the `@include` tag, so you can just use the facade directly:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    @include('component.input',[
        'label' => 'Last Name',
        'name' => 'last_name',
        'type' => 'text',
        'placeholder' => Auth::user()->last_name,
        'class' => '',
        'errorMessage' => "required"
    ])
</div>
```